# Adjust System Total as a result of .onDelete

Tags: swift, swiftui

The listView structure below displays coreData and uses onDelete to delete individual entries in coreData. The display of coreData entries and deleting of entries all work fine. When deleting an entry I would like to subtract the entry value from a system total found in the class UserData (rateArray). I'm having trouble with my call to my UserData method adjTotal. If I put all my parameters in the call I get about six errors, but if I first reduce the coreData parameters to three simple parameters I still get one error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". I'm guessing this error has to do with non-view calculations but I'm not sure how to avoid this.  id, entryDsc, entryDT, entryCat, moneyS, and rate are attributes of my coreData entity CurrTrans.

```
class UserData:  ObservableObject {
    
    var rateArray = [Double] ()

    func adjTotal( moneyS: String, rate: Double, cat: Int) -> () {
        var dq: Double = 0
        var moneyD: Double = 0
        
        moneyD = Double(moneyS) ?? 0.0
        dq = moneyD * rate
        totalArray[cat] -= dq
    }


struct listView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    var cat: Int = 0
    var money: String = ""
    var xchRate: Double = 0.0
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: CurrTrans.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: []
    ) var currTrans: FetchedResults<CurrTrans>

 var body: some View {

     NavigationView {
         List {
             ForEach(currTrans, id: \.self) { item in
                 VStack (alignment:.leading) {
                     HStack {
                            
                         if item.entryDT != nil {
                                Text(item.entryDT!.getFormattedDate())
                         }
                         Spacer()
                            
                         if item.moneyS != nil {
                             Text("\(item.moneyS!)")
                         }
                     }     
                     Text("Category: \(categories[Int(item.entryCat)])")
                        
                     if item.entryDsc != nil {
                         Text("\(item.entryDsc!)")
                     }
                  }
               }
               .onDelete { indexSet in
                   for index in indexSet {
                       viewContext.delete(currTrans[index])
                        
                       let cat = currTrans[index].entryCat
                       let money = currTrans[index].moneyS
                       let xchRate = currTrans[index].rate
                        
                       self.userData.adjTotal( money: String, xchRate: Double, cat: Int)
                   }
                   do {
                        try viewContext.save()
                   } catch {
                       print(error.localizedDescription)
                   }
               }
           }
           .navigationBarTitle("Entry Listing", displayMode: .inline)
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `adjTotal` function expects three parameters:

```
func adjTotal( moneyS: String, rate: Double, cat: Int)
```

However, this is wrong - you can't just pass `String` (or other types):

```
self.userData.adjTotal( money: String, xchRate: Double, cat: Int)
```

You need to pass the already calculated values:

```
let money = currTrans[index].moneyS
let xchRate = currTrans[index].rate
let cat = currTrans[index].entryCat

self.userData.adjTotal(money: money, xchRate: xchRate, cat: cat)
```

For more information see the documentation of [Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html).

Comment: if I change my method header to func adjTotal( money: money, rate: rate, cat: cat) -> () { and call to self.userData.adjTotal( money: money, xchRate: xchRate, cat: cat) I get 3 errors for the header and one for the call. If I change the method header to func adjTotal( money: String, rate: Double, cat: Int) -> () { I have only 1 error for the call -- the same as above Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I tested the parameters in the call to adjTotal individually one at a time and found two errors in the code above the call.

cat is a Int16 since it is stored in CoreData. I added casting to Int:
let cat = Int(currTrans[index].entryCat)

The value (money) is a String that needs nil coalescing:
let money = currTrans[index].moneyS ?? ""

Thanks pawello2222 for your help.